# How to change the compression style of a TIFF image using sips?

Tags: command-line, tiff, sip

I am a Mac guy,

How to get the PackBits compression using [sips](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html)?

Below one for LZW works fine.

```
sips -s formatOptions lzw /DefaultGroup.tif
```

But this fails:

```
sips -s formatOptions packbits /DefaultGroup.tif
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works.
But still I could not find the actual answer to my query.

```
 int compression = NSTIFFCompressionPackBits;

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)dataToWrite, NULL);

CGImageRef imageRef =  CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);

CFMutableDictionaryRef saveMetaAndOpts = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(nil,0,&kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,  &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFMutableDictionaryRef tiffProfsMut = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(nil, 0,
&kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,  &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(tiffProfsMut, kCGImagePropertyTIFFCompression, CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &compression));  
CFDictionarySetValue(saveMetaAndOpts, kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary, tiffProfsMut);

NSURL *outURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filename];
CGImageDestinationRef dr = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL ((CFURLRef)outURL, (CFStringRef)@"public.tiff" , 1, NULL);
CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, imageRef, saveMetaAndOpts);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(dr);

CFRelease(dr);
[outURL release];
CFRelease(tiffProfsMut);
CFRelease(saveMetaAndOpts);
CFRelease(imageRef);

CFRelease(source);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
sips -s formatOptions packbits /DefaultGroup.tif
```

try

```
sips -s formatOptions pacbits /DefaultGroup.tif
```

In other words, use 'pacbits' instead of 'packbits'.

Kind of surprising, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

loopqoob is right.

The man page for sips is wrong.   You must use "pacbits" NOT "packbits" when using sips.

In other words, this will work.  It does on my Mac running High Sierra:

E.G.

```
sips -s format tiff -s formatOptions pacbits '/Users/rob/Downloads/image20.jpg' --out '/Users/rob/Downloads/image20.tiff
```

After I do that, I can open up the tiff image in Preview.  Click "Tools" and then "Show Inspector" on the drop down menu.  You will see that the TIFF image is compressed with Packbits.   (Preview shows the correct name of the compression used).